# Vue js - unknown transform 'Collections'

Tags: vue-component

I'm New to Vue can u please anyone help with this error?

whenever i run script watch it return **x (vue) unknown Tranform 'collections'**

whether it is an problem with my api ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add more details to the question and possibly add code and error screenshot for the reference.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. when i run this **bili src/components/index.js --outDir ./es/ --filename index.js --plugin eslint,vue --format es --watch** im getting this error in my component  **x (vue) unknown Tranform 'collections'**